# Switching id names in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Working on chess board using html and javascript. I am trying to add a function so that the user can flip the perspective of the board and running into a glitch that I understand, but can't figure out how to solve. Code as below....

```
function flipBoard(){

    document.getElementById("a8").id = "h1";
    document.getElementById("a7").id = "h2";
    document.getElementById("a6").id = "h3";
    document.getElementById("a5").id = "h4";
    document.getElementById("a4").id = "h5";
    document.getElementById("a3").id = "h6";
    document.getElementById("a2").id = "h7";
    document.getElementById("a1").id = "h8";

    document.getElementById("h8").id = "a1";
    document.getElementById("h7").id = "a2";
    document.getElementById("h6").id = "a3";
    document.getElementById("h5").id = "a4";
    document.getElementById("h4").id = "a5";
    document.getElementById("h3").id = "a6";
    document.getElementById("h2").id = "a7";
    document.getElementById("h1").id = "a8";
}
```

So.... I thought this would work just fine, but discovered that this wreaks havoc on my board by position half white, half black pieces on both sides of the board. The problem of course is that after the original "a1" square is renamed to "h8", there are now TWO "h8" squares, and at the end of the code it switches both back to "a1".

I have no idea how to get the id names to switch at the same time, otherwise I'd have to add a whole lot of code switching the id names to some third name as a place holder before switching them over to the desired name. Possible, but tedious and I feel there has to be a simpler way to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reduce the repetition of your current code by generating the id values programmatically in a loop:

```
function flipBoard(){
    var a, h, aVal, hVal, aEl, hEl;

    for(a = 8, h = 1; a > 0; --a, ++h) {
        aVal = 'a' + a;
        hVal = 'h' + h;

        // Store off the current values
        aEl = document.getElementById(aVal);
        hEl = document.getElementById(hVal);

        // swap them
        aEl.id = hVal;
        hEl.id = aVal;
    }
}
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fayL1uj/)

Comment: @SteampunkWizard - depending on how much code you have implemented and how much manipulating the data/model as part of the view gets, you may want to consider separating the view from the modal.  That would give you a standard, static representation of the board for your game logic and a simple way to manipulate the view without affecting it in any way: [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fayL1uj/1/)

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! That worked perfectly. I was worried if there were going to be any interactions with adding b-g files to the code, but no issues at all. At the moment, if I already have pieces on the board, the board id will switch, but the pieces won't. My next step is to run a function to save the current board position into two arrays for pieces and board squares and reload the board position. For the moment, I have no intention of hooking an engine to this board. The purpose of this program is to give me a free form board to use when teaching chess.

Answer (score 3):

Save the reference to the element in variable. For example:

```
function flip(){ 
   var aEight = document.getElementById("a8"),
       hOne = document.getElementById("h1");

    aEight.id = "h1";
    hOne.id = "a8";
}
```

By separating out the steps of finding your elements and changing their ids, you'll easily be able to keep track of the flipped elements.

Comment: Adding on to this, I'd use these variables throughout your app, not just in this function, so that you're only using getElementById once per square.  Either that or have them all saved in one two-dimensional array variable.